# Angular2 http get request with header fails

Tags: angular

I am trying to do a simple get request via angular2 http like this: (the token is present also retrieved from a post to my api)

```
let idToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
let authHeader = new Headers();
if (idToken) {
    authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + idToken);
}
return this._http.get('http://someapicall-to-my-custom-api', {headers: authHeader})
.map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)),
    () => console.log('Completed')
);
```

If i call my api without the headers it returns a good result. The moment i add the header i only runs through the error in subscribe. The problem is that i need to start sending the header with it to get some protected data and so far that is failing.

In the console i see no usefull information at all i just see this:

```
{"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"Ok","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}
```

On the GET request to the api i see no 200 ok but i do when i didnt add the headers. Also there are no response headers.

If i try to use postman to do the same, it works without problems in that program.

I hope someone can point me into the right direction. Could it be my api? How can i debug this?

Comment: Do you see at the server if a request is received?

Comment: Thx for your suggestion but i am not sure how to check that. What's so weird to me is that if i just don't send any headers i get a ok 200 result in the console. Its just if i try to add a header to it it fails and i get the result described in the post. The API im trying to do the http get to is a custom Laravel API with dingo to which i also added a header to allow cross domain for example.

Comment: It mighr be a CORS issue where custom headers need to be explicitely allowed, but I would expect a proper error message. Do you not control the server? What kind of server is it?

Comment: Well i had a CORS issue before when trying to post to a non protected end point in my API and i added this: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *'); to the Laravel routes file which solved that. So at this point i figured i should not have any issues relating to that anymore. I control both the front end (angular2) and the api backend which is my custom Laravel.

Comment: Wow you are the best!!! I just added this to my API: header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization'); And it started to work!! THANKS MILLIONS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

See also [CORS: Autorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909996/cors-autorization-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers)

Answer (score 1):

By adding this to the routes.php in my Laravel API, which was the api i was trying to call it started to work. Thanks for Günter Zöchbauer to give me the idea to add that there :)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this happens in the context of electron apps and chrome extensions as well.

The cause is that there is proxy in between you app and your server. (usually an authentication proxy server for intranet domains). This new url will not match the page URL where you app was loaded from or other trusted URLs.

Unfortunately you don't know the domain on your proxy server to add it to your trusted URLs. So there is no way to fix this.